# Shuffle a list which can't output the same number twice

Tags: c#, list, random

I have two `List<int>`, Let's call one `Pool` and the other one `Used`.

`Pool` has integers between `0` and `X` and `Used` has integers which has been drawn from the `Pool` list.

So what I'm trying to achieve is to get a random draw from the `Pool` list where the draw isn't contained anywhere inside the `Used` list. If I've used all the numbers up, I want it to jump back to `0`.

Here's what I came up with, but it didn't work

```
int x = 0;
int ri = 0;
Random r = new Random();
while (true)
{
    ri = r.Next(0, Pool.Count);
    if (!Used.Contains(ri))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        x += 1;
    }

    if(x == Used.Count) // Here I check if it has tried getting a new random number but failed since the Pool is "empty"
    {
        ri = 0;
        UsedIndexes = new List<int>();
        break;
    }
}
```

When I use this, it does some crazy thing where it jumps from `0-2-4-6-8` etc, which I have NO idea why.

Shouldn't this be working? How do I fix it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Does the published code compile?

Comment: How are you "getting" anything? This code snippet does not output anything.

Comment: You're not actually inserting or reading any numbers from the Used or Pool lists... you're only seeing if a random number between 0 and the size of the `Pool` list is a number in `Used`. What? Also, each time you hit the `UsedIndexes = new List<int>()` line of code you'll be setting `UsedIndexes` to a new empty list. Is that your intent?

Comment: @JeffBridgman This snippet is part of a function which gives me values from those two lists (they aren't declared in the function, I put them here in the snippet to show), I fill them with different functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int> pool = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> used = new List<int>();
Random r = new Random();

while (pool.Count > 0)
{
    int idx = r.Next(pool.Count);
    used.Push(pool[idx]);
    pool.RemoveAt(idx);
}
// Now used contains random iteration of 1,2,3,4,5
// To loop again, just assign used back to pool and repeat
pool = used;
used = new List<int>();
```

Alternatively, do a Fisher-Yates shuffle (which can be done in place) and then just go through them 0 to n. When you reach n, reshuffle and start back at 0.

Comment: Yeah the Fisher method looked useful, since I don't have to use the "Used" list anymore.

Comment: That assumes that there are no duplicated numbers in the `pool` list.  If there are then extract a shorter list, containing only non-duplicates, and shuffle that shorter list.

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you'd like.

```
Random r = new Random();
var pool = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var used = new List<int>();

while(used.Count != pool.Count) {
    var ri = r.Next(0, pool.Count);
    var choice = pool[ri];
    if (!used.Contains(choice)) {
        Console.WriteLine(choice);
        used.Add(choice);
    }
}

used.Clear();
```

Comment: @MattBurland Write me some failing tests and I'll fix them, hehe. Let's get all TDD on this algorithm! Joking aside, thanks for the notice. I'm having trouble spotting the condition under which it wouldn't exit. Care to enlighten us?

Comment: It's pretty unlikely, but let's say you random number generator continuously generated the number `1` *every single time* which is actually, just as unlikely as any other *specific* sequence of numbers for a truly random process. In that case your `!used.Contains(choice)` would always return false and your `used` would never get filled up. So that's a silly example, but imagine instead of 5 numbers you have 500,000 numbers. Once you have selected 499,999 how long would it take to pick that final number with your algorithm? Worst case?